# Group DataMapper records, then sort within those groups

Tags: ruby, orm, ruby-datamapper

I have records that I'd like to sort like this:

```
         Status       Date
Frank   STATUS_A   Jan 1, 2013
Jenny   STATUS_A   Feb 2, 2013
Alice   STATUS_A   Mar 3, 2013
Bob     STATUS_B   Jan 1, 2013
Zeke    STATUS_B   Feb 12, 2013
Harry   STATUS_B   Apr 4, 2013
```

Group together by `Status` and then sort by `Date` within each group.

Cannot figure out how to do this in ruby DataMapper.

I tried something like:

```
Person.all(:fields => [:status], :unique => true, :order => [:date.asc])
```

But got:

```
DataMapper::ImmutableError - Immutable resource cannot be lazy loaded
```

I also tried:

```
Person.all(:order => [:status]).all(:order => [:date])
```

This does the initial status grouping fine, but the second date ordering isn't constrained within each status group.

Comment: Nice, seems to work :) Can you list it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works:

```
Person.all(:order => [:status, :date])
```